# Python: Use private static method as default

Tags: python

I have a class member which accepts a function:

```
class A:

    def func(self, method):
       ...
```

I want to set a default method since that behavior is desired 99% of the time. 
This default behavior is static since it does not depend on any members of the class. However, I would like this default method to be private and invisible to the user. Is there any way of accomplishing that?

This is what I have tried:

1. ```
   class A:

       @staticmethod
       def __meth(x):
          pass

       def func(self, method = meth):
          pass
   ```

   Error: `'staticmethod' object is not callable`
2. ```
   class A:

       @staticmethod
       def __meth(x):
          pass

       def func(self, method = A.__meth):
          pass
   ```

   Error: `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`
3. ```
   class A:

       @staticmethod
       def __meth(x):
          pass

       def func(self, method = self.__meth):
          pass
   ```

   Error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

I am using Python 3.5 and do not want to rely on newer features.

Comment: There is no private in Python. And if there were, it would be far from the desired default behavior. What you can get is name mangling. Do you really want to name mangle all your methods? Why?!

Comment: I understand that there is no "real" private. But I want to mangle the name so as to discourage its use for anything but this specific application

Comment: Just remove the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: Wouldn't using a `lambda` be an option?

Comment: While that works, Lint starts to throw a bunch of warnings about how it should be static

Comment: A lambda would be a bit tricky because it is not a simple one-line function

Comment: Perhaps this is just a case where I should ignore lint then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly idiomatic to use `None` as the default and assign it as needed:

```
class A:

    @staticmethod
    def __meth(x):
        print(x)

    def func(self, method=None):
        if method is None:
            method = self.__meth

        method("x")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems start with your default parameter. These parameters are evaluated whilst the class definition is being read, and so class `A` is not yet defined.

You should handle it like a normal default parameter:

```
class A:

    @staticmethod
    def __meth(x):
       print('meth')

    def func(self, method = None):
        if method is None:
            self.__meth(1)
        else:
             method()


def foo():
    print('foo')

a = A()

a.func()
a.func(foo)
```

Output:

```
meth
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delay name resolution by putting it into a lambda:

```
class A:

   @staticmethod
   def __meth(x):
       pass

   def func(self, method = lambda s: A.__meth(s)):
       pass
```